# Surinam nationality and Carte Sejours validity

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, france

A person with Surinam nationality and passport also have a Carte Sejours from French Guyana which is valid for 10 years.

We know that that person can travel legally without any limitation of duration of stay and entries/departures to/from France and vv from French Guyana.

The question is:
Can that person also travel to other Schengen countries unlimited once entered France and stay there without any limits?
Can that person for example also enter or depart from another country airport then France?

If the person is allowed to stay unlimited in France then one would expect that it is the same for all Schengen countries.

Will save a lot of visa applications and money.